# 'Dissolve with stats' plug-in unexpected behaviour

Tags: qgis

I'm encountering a problem with the 'Dissolve with stats' tool.

I have a geopackage, and I want to dissolve all the features together. For some fields I want to sum the values, for others I want the means. I have created a field just for the purposes of the dissolve, with the same value for all of the features.

The result I'm getting from the tool is just the first feature from the original geopackage, with no stats calculated and just the original values.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked with the plugin provider and their bug reports?

Comment: Just submitted a bug, hopeful it wil get seen.

Answer (score 0):

There is now the official 'Aggregate' tool which does the job - https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate